# How can I set jQuery datepicker value ? ("setDate" not working)

Tags: jsp, jquery-ui-datepicker

i'm facing problems setting jQuery datepicker date value. I'm retrieving a date from sql database, then trying to set it to the datepicker after formatting it.
my jsp code looks like

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                        <label>Date de Debut</label><span style="color:red;"></span>
                         <form:input
                            path="roles[0].startDate"
                            class="form-control" 
                            type="date"
                            pattern="dd-mm-yyyy"
                            name="dateDebut" 
                            id="dateDeDebut" 
                            required="true" />
                    </div>
```

my Jquery code looks like

```
var start = row.roles[0].startDate;
    var date_start = new Date(start);
    var startDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date_start);//gives me this format "dd/mm/yyyy"

    $('#dateDeDebut').datepicker();
    $('#dateDeDebut').datepicker("setDate", startDate);
```

[image: all fields ok, only datepickers not working not showing values]

Comment: so what doesn't work ? what error you are getting ? please add more details in your question

Comment: i'm not getting any error, after that code execution i'm assuming the datepicker input with the id "dateDeDebut" will be set to the startDate content value. but nothing happening. when i type console.log(startDate) it shows me a date like that "24/02/2020" but when i type console.log($('#dateDeDebut').val()) it return nothing, means its empty

Comment: remove `type="date"` and put `type="text"` and check if that works

Comment: thank you Swati i appreciate your help, but with the text type i'm getting error saying you must respect the required format. I'm sure the format is correct cause i set it to the same pattern for the DB incoming value, the JSP file and the jQuery code. this only appears with the type text but with date type its ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the `type="date"` because you are using datepicker as well ,so just change the `type` of input whenever you need to apply datepicker on `dateDeDebut`.

Below is the working demo code :

```js
$(function() {
//let start be 12-02-2020 
  var start = "12-02-2020";
  var date_start = new Date(start);
  var startDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date_start); //gives me this format "dd/mm/yyyy"
//changing date to text
  $('input[type=date]').each(function() {
    this.type = "text";
  });
  $('#dateDeDebut').datepicker();
  $('#dateDeDebut').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
 //printing value on console
  console.log($('#dateDeDebut').val());

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
  <label>Date de Debut</label><span style="color:red;"></span>
  <input path="roles[0].startDate" class="form-control" type="date" pattern="dd-mm-yyyy" name="dateDebut" id="dateDeDebut" required="true" />
</div>
```